# Compute $P(X>2U)$ for $X$ exponential and $U$ uniform on $(0,1)$

Tags: probability, probability-theory, probability-distributions

I am trying to calculate the $P(X>2U)$, where $X-exp(\lambda), U-Uniform(0,1)$.
But my answer calculated by hand doesn't matched with the answer calculated using Mathematica.

$P(X>2U)=\int_{u=0} ^1 \int_{x=2u} ^2 \lambda exp(-\lambda x) dx du=-exp(-2\lambda)-\frac{exp(-2\lambda)-1}{2\lambda}$.

But from mathematica, I got:

$-\frac{e^{-2 \lambda }-1}{2 \lambda }$

This does not make any sense at all.

Comment: You should replace your title with a meaningful title revealing the content of the question at hand. You want the title to be informative and representative of the question, and not an appeal for attention or help.

Comment: Why is your inner integral from $2u$ to $2$?

Comment: yeah， should from 2u to infinity.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If $U\sim\mathsf U(0,1)$, then $2U\sim\mathsf(0,2)$. Assuming $X$ and $Y:=2U$ are independent, we compute
\begin{align}
\mathbb P(X>Y) &= \int\limits_{\{(x,y)\ :\ x>y\}} f_{X,Y}(x,y)\ \mathsf d(x\times y)\\
&= \int_0^2\int_y^\infty f_X(x)\ \mathsf dx\ f_Y(y)\ \mathsf dy\\
&= \int_0^2\int_y^\infty \lambda e^{-\lambda x}\ \mathsf dx\ \frac12\ \mathsf dy\\
&= \int_0^2 \frac12 e^{-\lambda y}\ \mathsf dy\\
&= \frac1{2\lambda}(1-e^{-2\lambda}).
\end{align}